# Google Analytics is not working in Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, google-analytics, gunicorn

1. I have setup a simple website in Flask served by Nginx and Gunicorn (http://altanga.com).
2. Included Google tracking code in base.html and extended in every
   single template and I see the code is there when I view page source.

But, it is not capturing any activity. It's been over 2 hours already, but no luck.

Below is my ga code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-106188456-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Please help.

Comment: Privacy badger sees the tracker, can you see live users, but not other stats, or nothing at all?

Comment: absolutely nothing. I am looking at Real-Time->Overview.

Comment: Are you using anything like Privacy Badger or similar that might be stopping your browser tracking you? Also, can you check the ID is correct.

Comment: I checked the ID. All is correct: UA-106188456-1 on both ends. I am not using any Privacy Badger. But, how do I check if it is there? (sorry for the ridiculous question. I am more of data analysis, rather than building website)

Comment: I tried browsing from my iPhone and iPad. The same.

Comment: I checked the site and I can see a google analytics object defined in my console. Try to see if you got any hit from the visit.

Comment: 0 unfortunately. I am puzzled

Comment: Magically it started working. I did nothing but rather sent Google feedback about the issue. As soon as I find out what really happened, I post it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
{% import "bootstrap/google.html" as google %}

{% block scripts %}
{{super()}}
{{google.uanalytics('UA-106188456-1')}}
{% endblock %}
```